# Android Studio build failed : An issue was found when checking AAR metadata

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

So i have been trying to run my project but i am encountering issues with com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0-alpha01 due to the "UpsideDownCake" API requirement.

This is the error message :

> Dependency 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0-alpha01' requires libraries and applications that
> depend on it to compile against codename "UpsideDownCake" of the
> Android APIs.
> :app is currently compiled against android-33.
> Recommended action: Use a different version of dependency 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0-alpha01',
> or set compileSdkPreview to "UpsideDownCake" in your build.gradle
> file if you intend to experiment with that preview SDK.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in their [release notes for 1.10.0-alpha01](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.10.0-alpha01), you need to use `android-UpsideDownCake` as `compileSdkVersion` in your app level `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion "android-UpsideDownCake"
    ...
}
```

However if you don't really need to be on the alpha version, use the latest stable version instead:

```
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in this version:

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0-alpha01'`

When I upgraded to the recommended new version, I was getting an error. After reviewing the log, I realized that I needed to upgrade `compileSdkPreview` for the new version to work correctly.

[image]

If you are going to use the new version, you should add the following.

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0-alpha01'`

Make sure you download the SDK.

[image]

`build.gradle(:app)` you should update the value in the file as below:

`compileSdkVersion "android-UpsideDownCake"`

For detailed information, you can check: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/setup-sdk#kts